# How to cut off an unused space in a custom view?

Tags: android

I have a custom `View` which has bigger height than its inner drawn content. I tried to set desired content height manually in code like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
        int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

        int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);
        centerX = chosenDimension / 2 - offsetCenterX;
        centerY = chosenDimension / 2 - offsetCenterY;

        setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension - 200); //IN HERE I`M TRYING TO CROP THE VIEWS HEIGHT
    }
```

But it appears that my `View` scales down. I do not need this.
My solution to this was to reset ALL the dimensions in `dimen.xml`, but it kinda wrong. Any idea how to crop it in a right and easy way?

**Here it is a picture what I want to cut off**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would not have to cut off that space. Just set the correct values in `onMesaure()`. And to scale all dimens in `dimens.xml`